# Laravel query data based on a column

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I have a table `basicinfo` with a column `dateOfEnrollment` of type `date`. I want to query all the records that are enrolled for more than 4 years. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use Carbon.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$now->subYears(4);
$records = Model::whereDate('dateOfEnrollment', '>', $now)->get();
```

Comment: my coloumn structure is of date so will it work on date only . the dateOfEnrollment is stored as "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: From bitter experience, always best to store them as timestamps, rather than dates (even if the time section is irrelevant) and then cast them to dates in your model. That will automatically return the date as a Carbon object.

Comment: But sorry, yes, it should work on date field only. It ignores the time element if you use whereDate() on a timestamp field.